# Adding computed column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to add computed column that calculates the sum of selected column.

this is what i've done but has an error..

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblEM_Reimbursement
ADD [Amount] AS (SELECT SUM(Total) FROM dbo.tblEM_ReimbursementEntry WHERE ReimbursementID = ReimbursementID)
```

it says

> Msg 1046, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, the error message seems clear and understandable to me. You're not allowed to access data from other tables in a computed column. (Nor even other rows in the same table)

Comment: nah.. so i need to use Function.. i always encounter problem with functions inside computed column because i can't modify it in the future..

Comment: Personally, in this case, I'd see whether a view (possibly indexed) would satisfy the requirement.

Comment: Damien is right : a JOIN in a view would be better performance wise

Comment: A computed column can access and use other columns in the same row, e.g. `ALTER TABLE dbo.Invoice ADD GrandTotal AS Total + Tax + Freight` but it cannot reference other rows in the table

Comment: Read my answer, that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a user-defined function. **Non tested** code below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Get_ReimbursementEntry (@ReimbursementID int)
RETURNS DECIMAL(10,2)
AS BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT SUM(Total) FROM dbo.tblEM_ReimbursementEntry WHERE ReimbursementID = ReimbursementID)
END
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.tblEM_Reimbursement
ADD [Amount] AS (dbo.Get_ReimbursementEntry (ReimbursementID))
GO
```

but beware of the performance implications

Comment: i already tried this but i always got a problem if i modify this function in the future

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Trigger`. `Trigger` is a automated function written in `PL/SQL` whcih is called 
*after* or *before* a particular event.

Read [this tutorial](http://plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-triggers.htm) for better understanding.

For SQL-Server read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25600/Triggers-Sql-Server) and [this](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/OJ97170312-Different-Types-of-SQL-Server-Triggers.html).

**Example**:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee_Test
(
    Emp_ID INT Identity,
    Emp_name Varchar(100),
    Emp_Sal Decimal (10,2)
)

INSERT INTO Employee_Test VALUES ('Anees',1000);
INSERT INTO Employee_Test VALUES ('Rick',1200);    
INSERT INTO Employee_Test VALUES ('John',1100);
INSERT INTO Employee_Test VALUES ('Stephen',1300);
INSERT INTO Employee_Test VALUES ('Maria',1400);
```

Suppose you have another table:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee_Test_Audit
(
    Emp_ID int,
    Emp_name varchar(100),
    Emp_Sal decimal (10,2),
    Audit_Action varchar(100),
    Audit_Timestamp datetime
)
```

This trigger is fired after an INSERT on the table. Let’s create the trigger as:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON [dbo].[Employee_Test] 
FOR INSERT
AS
declare @empid int;
declare @empname varchar(100);
declare @empsal decimal(10,2);
declare @audit_action varchar(100);

select @empid=i.Emp_ID from inserted i; 
select @empname=i.Emp_Name from inserted i; 
select @empsal=i.Emp_Sal from inserted i;   
set @audit_action='Inserted Record -- After Insert Trigger.';

insert into Employee_Test_Audit
       (Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Emp_Sal,Audit_Action,Audit_Timestamp) 
values(@empid,@empname,@empsal,@audit_action,getdate());

PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
GO
```

Comment: That would be at least one trigger on each of the two tables instead of one UDF or (better) one join / view, not advisable.